# Suppress the suspend option at shutdown

Tags: virtualbox, suspend, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine on a MacOS Mojave host. I can start the VM on the command line:

```
VBoxManage startvm my_ubuntu --type headless
```

The recommended way of shutting a VM down is

```
VBoxManage controlvm my_ubuntu acpipowerbutton
```

however, that fails - the GUI shows a splash menu:

```
Goodbye, Chris, would you like to 

<suspend image>
```

I've tried supressing this splash image using

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

and

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-shutdown-menuitem true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-restart-menuitem true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-menuitem true
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session user-show-menu false
```

rebooting every time, but the splash screen still shows.

Is there anything else I can try? Or is this a bug with the `acpipowerbutton` command in `VBoxManage`?

(I can get round this by SSHing in, and running `sudo shutdown`, or by using the GUI, but both are less convenient)

I've also noticed that running `sudo restart now` results in:

```
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

is this related? (If not, I'll edit and ask it in a new question...)